# how to close an open content panel in foundation zurb tab

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

here's my zurb foundation code with tabs :

[http : // codepen.io/vomaringo/pen/RPRdRr](http://http%20:%20//%20codepen.io/vomaringo/pen/RPRdRr)

I had like to close a panel tab by clicking in the tab again.
could it be done in zurb foundation with an option or could you help me with jquery?
Thanks for reading my post.
Regards
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the code here

**HTML**

```
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <li class="accordion-navigation">      
     <a href="#panel1a">Accordion 1</a>
     <a href="#panel2a">Accordion 2</a>
    <div id="panel1a" class="content active">
      Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
      <div id="panel2a" class="content">
      Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.accordion-navigation > a{width:200px;float:left;}
.content{display:block;float:none;width:100%;clear:both}
```

**jQuery**

```
   $(document).foundation();
$( ".tabs" ).click(function() {
  if ( $( '.content' ).hasClass('active')) {
    $('content').hide();
  }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/axvbLuja/

Comment: it looks good. i will try to switch from tab to accordion. thanks